# How can I send access.log files automatically to a specific email address after rotation?

Tags: log-files, apache-2.4

I am running `apache 2.4.9` on `ubuntu 14.04`. Apache rotates log files and archives them, so I end up with something like: `access.log.2.gz`, ... `access.log.N.gz`.

The problem with this is that it is hard to analyze them (I have to unarchive, analyze and remove them). Moreover, I do not really want these logs to lay around on the server (I would rather copy them to my local machine and remove them from server). Right now I am doing this manually, which is not so efficient.

So is there a way to configure apache to automatically send me an email with a log file right after apache rotated it? If this is not really a good idea or there is something better, I am opened to any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From man logrotate.conf

> ```
> mail address
> ```
>
> When a log is rotated out-of-existence, it is mailed to address. If no mail should be generated by a particular log, the
>   nomail directive may be used.
>
> ```
> mailfirst
> ```
>
> When using the mail command, mail the just-rotated file, instead of the about-to-expire file.
>
> ```
> maillast
> ```
>
> When using the mail command, mail the about-to-expire file, instead of the just-rotated file (this is the default).

So if you set those options in your logrotate config file(s), and reduce the `rotate` option to 0 then you should get what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you use logrotate to rotate the file (probably a great idea)..then you can put in postprocessing in the configuration file for the file being rotated.  If this is currently contained in a multiple file rule, then break it down and make the change.  This postprocessing could be to send a file to you.